# In bash script how do I ensure youtube-dl downloads all files in a playlist

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, error-handling, youtube-dl

I'm trying to automate downloading a playlist using youtube-dl using a bash script. I have been successful when there are no errors thrown by youtube-dl.

Lets say there is a content-too-short error, then I try to loop to complete the files in the playlist after sleeping for 90 seconds so as to not bombard the site.

However what I am experiencing that for some reason the sleep is not working as expected and site is being bombarded with subsequent request leading to a http 429.

What can I do to improve my script ... partial script displayed here

```
until youtube-dl --verbose --ignore-errors url-to-playlist; do 
        sleep 90; 
    done
```

Am I using the wrong loop? Is there a better way?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a playlist to youtube-dl, together with the command line option `--ignore-errors`. That means youtube-dl will attempt to download the entire list of videos before exiting; regardless of how many failures it will face along the way. So if video #2 would fail, then the request for video #3 would follow immediately after. I don't know how vigilant Google is, but that could already ring a bell over there.

And even after the last video in your playlist has been hit, how sure are you that youtube-dl returns a non-zero exit code? There is no mention of that in the [readme](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md), so I wouldn't be surprised if your `sleep 90` would never be executed.

Besides, what good is this loop anyway? Restarting youtube-dl with the same playlist will download everything all over again; including all videos that were downloaded successfully the first time. Though options `--no-overwrites` and `--continue` may help out here.

To prevent Google blocking your IP address (HTTP 429), I would suggest to use option `--sleep-interval`. Example:

```
youtube-dl --verbose --ignore-errors --sleep-interval 10 url-to-playlist
```

I'm not sure if the intention of your loop was to keep retrying a failed video until it eventually succeeds. I hope not; it is not very straightforward, since:

- You cannot use the exit code of youtube-dl to detect failure. You'd need to either cross-reference the output folder with your playlist, or parse youtube-dl's output.
- You'd need to implement some counter to restrict the number of retries; some problems don't disappear by themselves.

Comment: I live in China and use VPN to download educational videos from Youtube. Connection is very bad here, so often times youtube-dl will not finish. So I use the same exact loop to download videos except I remove `--ignore-errors` and the sleep command does get executed and everything works fine.

Comment: @Fazzolini Seems like you are commenting not so much on my answer, but rather on OP's question. If you feel your experiences could be valuable to OP (or others looking for a solution), then please post them as a separate answer to the question.

Comment: I though I was commenting on your statement that you wouldn't be surprised if `sleep 90` would never be executed. I wanted to add that it does get executed. Another part of my comment was about your question `what good is this loop anyway`. And my answer to that would be that it is indeed good, because it allows to accomplish the stated goal – to download the playlist.

Comment: @Fazzolini In OP's script, sleep is **never** reached because `youtube-dl --ignore-errors` always returns exit code 0. I deliberately did _not_ recommend removing `--ignore-errors` due to its disadvantage that a permanent failure on a single video (or worse, regular hick-ups on a flaky internet connection) may result in infinite retries. Your script (besides wasting bandwidth re-doing successful downloads of the first videos) is not guaranteed to ever reach the end of a long playlist. But your mileage may vary.